# How do I decode strings in 'utf-8'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm using tweepy to capture some tweets in Portuguese and I'm saving these tweets in a csv file. All tweet text we're saved with special characters and now I can't convert then to the correct format.

My coding for the tweet capture is:

```
csvFile = open('ua.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=usuario,count=10,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2018-12-01").items():
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

I'm reading the results like this:

```
test = pd.read_csv('ua.csv', header=None)
test.columns = ["date", "text"]
result = test['text'][0]
print(result)
'Aproveita essa promo\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o aqui!'
```

The result I need sholud be this:

```
print(result)
'Aproveita essa promoção aqui!'
```

I tried this code to convert:

```
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
```

and got this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should specify encoding when reading the data as well, otherwise the bytes on the hard drive are interpreted the wrong way. And actually I think the csv writer needs a `str` not a `bytes` and you should probably specify the encoding the for the CSV writer as well.

Comment: This is Python 3??

Comment: @davedwards that's the encoding of the *Python source code file*

Comment: Because it's irrelevant to the question, and for Python 3, it defaults to utf8 anyway

Comment: It would still be valid Python 2, or as any python 2 user should do, they can import the print function from `__future__`

Comment: Well, I suspect the problem is that you are writing the string representation of the bytes object to the file. When you write the tweets, don't use `tweet.text.encode('utf-8')]` i.e don't use `.encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file with the encoding to be used.  Don't encode it manually (Zen of Python: Explicit is better than implicit):

```
# newline='' per csv documentation
# encoding='utf-8-sig' if you plan on using Excel to read the csv, else 'utf8' is fine.
with open('ua.csv','a',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as csvFile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=usuario,count=10,
                               lang="en",
                               since="2018-12-01").items():
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

Here's a working example:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('ua.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as csvFile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(['timestamp','Aproveita essa promoção aqui!'])

test = pd.read_csv('ua.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', header=None)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
           0                              1
0  timestamp  Aproveita essa promoção aqui!
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a `bytes` object when you `.encode` your tweet, you don't need to do this.

A `csv.writer` object will coerce to string whatever you pass to it.

Note:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: s = 'Aproveita essa promoção aqui!'

In [3]: print(s)
Aproveita essa promoção aqui!

In [4]: print(s.encode())
b'Aproveita essa promo\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o aqui!'

In [5]: with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
   ...:     writer = csv.writer(f)
   ...:     writer.writerow([1, 3.4, 'Aproveita essa promoção aqui!'.encode()])
   ...:

In [6]: !cat test.txt
1,3.4,b'Aproveita essa promo\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o aqui!'
```

So just use:

```
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text])
```

Comment: for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=usuario,count=10,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2018-07-01").items():
    
   
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text])

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f614' in position 72: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

The pandas `read_csv` has an `encoding` parameter:

> Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. ‘utf-8’).